# List Properties names into a variable by Category Attribute

Tags: vb.net, winforms, typedescriptor

I am trying to **list** some **properties** names by **Category** attribute and put them into a **variable**.
For example, to get all properties names which "belong" to category **Appearance** and put them into a variable.

I have a similar example which resets specific properties, but I have to add them one by one which I want to avoid.

```
Dim _Form As Form = CType(Me, Form)
Dim ListOfPropertyNames As New List(Of String) From {"BackColor", "ForeColor"}
For Each _Property In ListOfPropertyNames
    Dim _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_Form)(_Property)
    If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_Form) Then
        If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_Form) IsNot Nothing Then
            _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Form)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: What is the problem? Maybe that `.CanResetValue()` returns `False`?

Comment: @Jimi there is not any problem with this part of code. I just use it for example. I want to get all properties names into a variable, listed by category name and not adding it one by one as this example does.

Comment: Allright, it's more clear now. I asked because, as the code is now, `.CanResetValue` will probably return `False` most of the time, if the properties you're testing have never been changed. I was wondering what you actually wanted to achieve. I'll see if I can show you a method to do what you're asking.

Comment: @Jimi OK, thank you very much for your time!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four possible scenarios in your question (that I can think of):

1. (More probable) Get the List of Properties ordered by `Category` and `DisplayName` and, if the [PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) method returns a positive result, reset the Property.
   Eventually, filter by `Category` inserting a `.Where` clause.
2. Get the List of Properties which belong to some pre-defined Categories and reset all the Properties that have a value different from the [DefaultValueAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ComponentModel.DefaultValueAttribute%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), checking the `PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` method result.
3. Same as above, but also adding a list of specific Properties to reset.
4. Get the List of Properties which belong to some pre-defined Categories and reset all the Properties no matter what `PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` thinks about it.

First case scenario:
Using LINQ, query the [TypeDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to build a list of [PropertyDescriptor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework) elements ordered by `Category` and `DisplayName`.
Check `PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` result and reset the Property value to its default if it has changed.

```
Dim PropertyCollection As List(Of PropertyDescriptor) = TypeDescriptor.
                                                        GetProperties(_Form).
                                                        OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                                        OrderBy(Function(item) item.Category).
                                                        ThenBy(Function(item) item.DisplayName).
                                                        ToList()

For Each _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor In PropertyCollection
    If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_Form) Then
        If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_Form) IsNot Nothing Then
            _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Form)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

The same with a Category filter:

```
Dim PropertyCollection As List(Of PropertyDescriptor) = TypeDescriptor.
                                                        GetProperties(_Form).
                                                        OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                                        OrderBy(Function(item) item.Category).
                                                        ThenBy(Function(item) item.DisplayName).
                                                        Where(Function(item) item.Category = "Appearance").
                                                        ToList()
```

The same, grouping the Properties list by `Category` using `GroupBy()`:

```
Dim _Form As Form = Me

Dim PropertyCollection As List(Of IGrouping(Of String, PropertyDescriptor)) = TypeDescriptor.
                                  GetProperties(_Form).
                                  OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                  OrderBy(Function(item) item.Category).
                                  ThenBy(Function(item) item.DisplayName).
                                  GroupBy(Function(item) item.Category).
                                  ToList()

'Extract one Category. It could also be a second For Each loop.
Dim CategoryPropertyList As List(Of PropertyDescriptor) = PropertyCollection.
                                                          SelectMany(Function(grp) grp).
                                                          Where(Function(prop) prop.Category = "Appearance").
                                                          ToList()

For Each _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor In CategoryPropertyList

    If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_Form) Then
        If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_Form) IsNot Nothing Then
            _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Form)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Second case scenario:
Using LINQ, query the `TypeDescriptor` to build a list of `PropertyDescriptor` elements related to a predefined Category list.
Check `PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` result and reset the Property value to its default if it has changed.

```
Dim _Form As Form = CType(Me, Form)
Dim ListOfCategoryNames As New List(Of String) From {"Appearance", "Behavior"}

For Each Category As String In ListOfCategoryNames
    Dim _PropertyCollection As List(Of PropertyDescriptor) = TypeDescriptor.
                                                             GetProperties(_Form).
                                                             OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                                             Where(Function(item) item.Category = Category).
                                                             ToList()

    For Each _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor In _PropertyCollection
        If _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_Form) Then
            If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_Form) IsNot Nothing Then
                _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Form)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Third case scenario:
Same as above, but add a filter for some specific properties:

```
Dim ListOfCategoryNames As New List(Of String) From {"Appearance", "Behavior"}
Dim ListOfPropertyNames As New List(Of String) From {"BackColor", "ForeColor", "AllowDrop", "Enabled"}

For Each Category As String In ListOfCategoryNames
    For Each PropertyName As String In ListOfPropertyNames
        Dim _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(_Form).
                                                        OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                                        Where(Function(item) item.Category = Category AndAlso
                                                                             item.Name = PropertyName).
                                                        FirstOrDefault()

        If (_PropertyDescriptor IsNot Nothing) AndAlso _PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_Form) Then
            If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_Form) IsNot Nothing Then
                _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Form)
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Fourth case scenario:
Using LINQ, query the `TypeDescriptor` to build a list of `PropertyDescriptor` elements related to a predefined Category list.
Check whether the `DefaultValueAttribute` of a Property is `Nothing`, because 
if it is, `PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` will skip it and look for a custom method alternative to get the result. Since no such methods are definined here, it will always return false unless it can detect that a Property has been changed.
If no `DefaultValueAttribute` is present, or `PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue()` returns `True`, resets all Properties values to Default, checking beforehand that a [ResetValue()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue%29%3Bk%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework&f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method exists for the Property.

```
Dim _Form As Form = CType(Me, Form)
Dim ListOfCategoryNames As New List(Of String) From {"Appearance", "Behavior"}

For Each Category As String In ListOfCategoryNames
    Dim _PropertyCollection As List(Of PropertyDescriptor) = TypeDescriptor.
                                                             GetProperties(_Form).
                                                             OfType(Of PropertyDescriptor).
                                                             Where(Function(item) item.Category = Category).
                                                             ToList()

    For Each _PropertyDescriptor As PropertyDescriptor In _PropertyCollection
        Dim _DefaultAttribute As DefaultValueAttribute = _PropertyDescriptor.
                                                         Attributes.OfType(Of DefaultValueAttribute).
                                                         Where(Function(item) item.IsDefaultAttribute).
                                                         FirstOrDefault

        If (_DefaultAttribute Is Nothing) Or (_PropertyDescriptor.CanResetValue(_Form)) Then
            If _PropertyDescriptor.GetType().GetMethod("ResetValue", BindingFlags.Public Or BindingFlags.Instance) IsNot Nothing Then
                If _PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(_Form) IsNot Nothing Then
                    _PropertyDescriptor.ResetValue(_Form)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: I am pretty sure one of these scenarios will do the "job"!!! Tommorow I'll test it and I'll inform you. Thank you very much for help and your precious time my friend!!! :-)

Comment: @Simonetos The Greek  I was still editing it. If you find something out of place, let me know (I modified it a lot, adding pieces here and there, maybe there's something to tune up).

Comment: My friend Jimi, I used the **first** case **scenario** with the **category filter** and it "worked" 100%!!! Thank you very much for this excellent and detailed answer. :-)

Comment: @Simonetos The Greek  Well, I'm glad it was useful :)